# Mongoose Vituals using Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to understand, can I use querys on virtuals?

for example if I have these 2 schemas.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        id: String,
        username: String,
        address: String,
    }
)

var gameSchema= new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        players: [String],
        winners: [String],
        losers: [String]
    }
)

var User = db.model('User', userSchema);
var Game = db.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

For every game I save only ID-s.

and I want to make virtual like this

```
gameSchema.virtual("playersInfo").get( function()
    {
        var playersInfo = [];
        async.each(this.players, function(player, done) {
            User.findOne({_id: this.players[i]}, function(err, user)) {
                if(err) done(err);
                playersInfo.push(user.toObject({virtuals: true}));
                done();
            }
        }, function(err) {
            if(err) return false;
        })
    }
)
```

I know that my virtual calls asychronely and I want to know, can I use something like this? e.g.

```
var game = Game.findOne({_id: someId}, function(err, game) {
    var g = game.toObject({virtuals: true});
    console.log(g.usersInfo);
})
```

Comment: Why can't you just use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?